# Leveling up perks offline

Tags: killing-floor

If I play a solo game or just host a game and play alone, I am able to level up my perks, but lose all experience gained playing alone when I switch to playing multiplayer instead.

I am asking how can I level my perks when playing solo games so the experience that I gain is not lost when I switch to multiplayer?

Does the game have to be set at a certain difficulty?

Comment: No one knows the answer? How can i
Lvl my perks but not playing multiplayer.

Comment: Try this: Host a multiplayer game using one of the vanilla maps ( i.e. one that came with the game ). If you have your perks there, it's not a multiplayer problem, it's a map problem.

Answer (score 2):

Levelling up your perks and getting achievements works exactly the same in singleplayer as it does in multiplayer, it has nothing to do with the difficulty setting. One thing you have to pay attention to when playing solo or hosting a server though is that the mutators you're using are **whitelisted**. Most of the public servers only use whitelisted mutators (if any at all), but when playing solo or hosting a server, it's easy to accidentally include a non-whitelisted mutator, especially since there's no in-game indication of a mutator being whitelisted or not.

Here's a [list of all whitelisted mutators](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/List_of_whitelisted_and_greylisted_mutators), make sure that no other mutators are active when you start your game and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Host a multiplayer game (listen server not dedicated,) and set the amount of players to one, so no one can join you.

Comment: #JustSayin Listen server is the in game server, dedicated is the out-of-the-game server, which is for hosting purposes.